# redirect when signout devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

*Rails 4.2 and Devise 5*

i'm using this [code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update) on my application_controller.rb to redirect user to the same page when they sign out

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   request.referrer || root_path
end
```

everything works fine, when user click sign out they will sign out and stay on the same page.

However if user try to sign out on failed validation edit profile*  the application throws  error. the log says "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users").

Any idea to improve the code?

*(for example, when user tries to change username and it's already taken, the form give validation error and the user sign out )

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can handle routing errors like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :handle_routing_error

  # added
  def routing_error
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(params[:path])
  end

  private

    def handle_routing_error
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "some alert text"
    end
end
```

Next add to **very end** of `Rails.application.routes.draw` block of your `routes.rb`

```
match "*path", to: "application#routing_error", via: :all
```

So if you have no last visited url you return to root_path. If you do have last visited url and it was good you return to it. If it was not good (like use case with validation) you return to root_path.

Comment: hi.. try this. but i can get this to work. sorry :( some say rescue might not work [https://coderwall.com/p/whjmra/handling-exceptions-in-your-rails-application]

Comment: @Aipack. Oh, sorry! I forgot one little code snippet which you should add to routes.rb and one mthod in ApplicationController. My bad. Updated the answer. Try it now!

Comment: @Aipack. **P.S.** My answer is working now in my own project. So it's totally tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if current_user
    request.referrer
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```

But what I do is having the same `after_sign_out_path_for` method in application_controller.rb

application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  request.referrer || root_path
end
```

And then add a `before_action :authenticate_user!` callback in your controller with all the methods where `user` is required. Like this,

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

end
```

That way when a user logs out while on the edit profile page, it will try to redirect him to the same page but before calling the `edit` action in `users_controller.rb` your `before_action` callback is being called and the user will automatically redirect to the sign in page.

This is absolutely what I prefer but you might not want it so you should go with the first solution.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. I've tried your first solution, unfortunately its still throws the same error. i haven't create a user_controller.rb  yet. i'm using devise user controller to change the profile.  its looks like request.referrer only catch the link without knowing the controller or action need to take . PATCH  /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer, use updated `after_sign_out_path_for` method to make it work.

Comment: hi.. updated with your answer, but now everything redirect to root_path when the user sign_out.. temporary i'm using dirty hack `if URI(request.referer).path == "/users" ` then redirect to root else using request referer. in the `after_sign_out_path_for` method